# Curl headers after using xargs

Tags: curl, http-headers, xargs

I am running the following command

`xargs -n 1 -t <"/myfilewithURLs" curl -v -uuser:password -H'"'Header1: value1'"' -H'"'Accept: application/json'"' -H'"'Header 3: value3'"' {}`

The command I get output is

`curl -v -user:password -H"Header 1: value 1" -H"Accept: application/json" -H"Header 3: value 3" https://mycorrectURL`

When I copy and paste this command into the console I get the output but when I run the full xargs command I get:

`* Rebuilt URL to: value 1"/` and curl obviously fails as I do not want the header as the url. Removing the curly brackets has no effect.

I presume this is something to do with the quoting as it does not seem to recognise that -H is a header and adds it as part of the command, but I can't find any resources to diagnose it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

I believe your `'"'` game is what causing the URL mix-up.
Try:

```
cat urls.txt | xargs -n 1 curl -u user:password -H "Header1: value1" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Header 3: value3"
```

you don't have to use `{}` here, as `xargs` will put the URL at the end of the `curl` command.

Also `curl` can handle mutiple URLs at once, so you can drop the `-n 1` and maybe benefit from keep-alived connections in case the the URLS are from the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably also want to add `-I {}` after the `xargs` and before the `curl`. There appears to be some "magic" behavior with `curl` that causes `xargs` to pass things to it as a `--url` instead of the default behavior of `{}` being replaced. Being explicit with your replacement token with `-I` is your best bet.

As the other answer mentioned, you are going a little overboard with the quotes, if you don't want variables expanded, use single quotes around the header strings, if you do want them expanded, use double quotes. If you want literal `'` in the data, to avoid messing up your expansion you can escape them like `-H "Data:\'Yay literally\'"`.